# Combine nested span tags

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

Can anyone assist me with trying to combine nested span tags?

I have some generated HTML that I trying to tidy up, and I'm having trouble getting this bit working.
Example HTML:

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif">
      <span style="color:black">
        <span style="font-size:medium">HELLO</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

What I want to do is combine the span tags into one with combined style, so the output is:

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:black;font-size:medium">HELLO</span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

I'm using C# in asp.net 4.0

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: What's generating the HTML? User control, classs, plain output within ASPX page?

Comment: [Use an XML parser or HTML parsing library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/21727).

Comment: @Brad.  The HTML is coming from an old system that we've been told cannot be changed, the example above is a very simplified example, there will be many nested spans throughout the output.

Comment: @mbeckish strange post you linked to there, but I think I get the idea!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution, which is not a one-liner kind of solution, but here it is: let's say you have the HTML text in a variable called `foo`, then you could do the following:

```
string replacement1 = "\"";
string replacement2 = "</span>";
string pattern = @"(?<=<span style=\")[^\"]+"; //Will match all the style strings
string pattern1 = @"(?<=<span style=)(.|\s)+\"(?=>[^<>].+</span>)"; //Will match from the first " to the last " before HELLO
string pattern2 = @"(</span>\s*)+"; //Will match any number of </span> tags
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(foo);
foreach (Match match in matches)
    replacement1 += match.Value + ";"; //Builds the new styles string
replacement1 += "\"";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern1);
string result = rgx.Replace(foo, replacement1); //Replace the multiple span style tags with a single one
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern2); 
string result = rgx.Replace(foo, replacement2); //Replace the multiple closing span tags with a single one
```

After the first replace you should get

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:black;font-size:medium">HELLO</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

and after the second replace:

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:black;font-size:medium">HELLO</span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

I couldn't test it (and it might have some typos), but it should work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get your expected result:

```
var css = "";
$("span").each(function (i) {
  css += $(this).attr('style')+';';
});
$("span").children().unwrap('<span>');
$("span").attr('style', css);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I wrote using version 1.4.6 of an HTML Parser called Html Agility Pack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Add this library to your project to use the following code.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(INPUT);
foreach(var currentSpanNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span")) {
    var parentNode = currentSpanNode.ParentNode;
    if (parentNode.Name != "span") continue;
    MergeStyleValuesLeft(parentNode.Attributes["style"], currentSpanNode.Attributes["style"]);
    parentNode.RemoveChild(currentSpanNode);
    parentNode.AppendChildren(currentSpanNode.ChildNodes);
}

var sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
doc.Save(sw);
```

At this point your new HTML code is in the StringBuilder object. The above code uses a function called MergeStyleValuesLeft(). I have a simplistic version of this function here. Depending on your requirements you could improve it to handle duplicate styles.

```
private void MergeStyleValuesLeft(HtmlAttribute leftAttribute, HtmlAttribute rightAttribute) {
    if (leftAttribute == null || rightAttribute == null) return;
    char[] styleSeparators = "; ".ToCharArray();
    string leftValue = leftAttribute.Value.Trim(styleSeparators);
    string rightValue = rightAttribute.Value.Trim(styleSeparators);
    leftAttribute.Value = String.Format("{0};{1}", leftValue, rightValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, been away since I asked the question, and in the meantime a colleague took a look and came up with a solution.

As I commented to Brad above, the HTML I posted is a very cut down sample, here is a link to our test code we use http://paste2.org/48hX9tpF

This is how my colleague did it:
First find the nested open

```
String outputHTML;
Regex re = new Regex("<span style=\"(.*?)\">(<span style=\"(.*?)\">)+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
outputHTML = re.Replace(inputHTML, new MatchEvaluator(StyleMerger));

static string StyleMerger(Match regexMatch)
{
    String matchedText = regexMatch.ToString();
    return matchedText.Replace("\"><span style=\"", ";");
}
```

And then find & replace nested close  tags

```
re = new Regex("</span>(</span>)+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
outputHTML = re.Replace(outputHTML, "</span>");
```

This results in this HTML http://paste2.org/xWFOKH3F

Answer (score -2):

`<strong>` should be put after `<span>` tag. Also there is a style property called font-weight which you can set to bold.

```
<p>
    <span style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:black;font-size:medium;font-weight:bold">HELLO</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This is not what he is asking. You can put this as a comment.